# Calculating the expected difference in observations

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $X_1,X_2$ be i.i.d $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

My tasks is to calculate the expected value of the function $T=|X_1-X_2|$.

Intuitively, I want to say that this value would equal the standard deviation, but I sort of doubt that this is the case because the standard deviation is the expected distance from the mean, and not just any observation... Any ideas?

Comment: Actually the standard deviation is the square root of the expected value of the square of the distance from the mean

Comment: It might help if you considered the distribution of $X_1-X_2$ and then of  $|X_1-X_2|$

Comment: Without trying anything fancy, did you try finding $E(T)=\iint |x_1-x_2|f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)\,dx_1\,dx_2$ ?

Answer (score 0):

As $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$, we directly have the distribution of $X_1-X_2$, namely

$$X_1-X_2\sim\mathcal N(0,2\sigma^2)$$

Define $$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\quad,\,x\in\mathbb R$$ as the pdf of standard normal distribution.

Then,

\begin{align}
E(|X_1-X_2|)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\int_{\mathbb R} |x|\phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)\,dx
\\\\&=\sqrt{2}\sigma\int_{\mathbb R} |t|\phi(t)\,dt \qquad\qquad,\,\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}=t
\\\\&=2\sqrt{2}\sigma\int_0^\infty t\phi(t)\,dt
\\\\&=-2\sqrt{2}\sigma \int_0^\infty\phi'(t)\,dt
\\\\&=-2\sqrt{2}\sigma\lim_{A\to\infty}\left[\phi(t)\right]_{0}^{A}
\\\\&=2\sqrt{2}\sigma\,\phi(0)
\\\\&=\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\end{align}